# Adding Objective C framework inside Swift Framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, bridging-header

I am writing a Cocoa Framework for iOS in Swift language. I need to add a third party framework (written in Objective-C) inside this framework. I have added headers to the bridging file. But when i build the project i get the following error:

"using bridging headers with framework targets is unsupported"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `import ObjcFrameworkName` instead of using bridging header.

To make this possible objc framework must contain `.modulemap` file with exported module name and umbrella header for all public headers of this framework.

Comment: Is there a way make it if a sub framework doesn't contain .modulemap? For example GoogleAnalytics pod. I want to add it to my framework, but all the headers are invisible for my Swift files. Bridging is not supported for frameworks. :(